# Remove pages from Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have my Google Analytics tracking code held in my header.php include file.  How can I remove this from certain pages?  There are a couple of pages I don't wish to track for various reasons.

I've tried a regex filter in GA but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Just do not insert the code for those pages and you should be fine. Make a decision in your header like @Mario answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's inserted in your own server side code, why don't you just add some `if()` around it to only embed it if some regex doesn't match (check current request) or some flag isn't set? Filtering on GA sounds a bit like a not so optimal solution as the dataset will be created already.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this the other day but had issues - today it's worked, I think I must have echoed the GA code incorrectly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/?id=154077');
header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow', true);
```